# Linker Errors with casablanca in VS2015 while trying to build a simple HTTP listener

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rest, casablanca

As part of the learning process about Rest services, i am trying to build a simple HTTP listener using the Microsoft c++ REST sdk "casablanca". My aim initially is to test if it can receive a simple POST request pointed at localhost and save the text in a file.

I am building this project on VS2015. I used the built-in package manager to find and install the sdk, and downloaded the required header files from github and added them as additional include directories. When trying to build , i keep getting "unresolved external symbol" errors with the error code LNK2019

Here is the code so far

```
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::experimental::listener;
using namespace utility;
using namespace std;

#define TRACE(msg)            wcout << msg;
#define TRACE_ACTION(a, k, v) wcout << a << L" (" << k << L", " << v << L")\n";

map<utility::string_t, utility::string_t> dictionary;



void handle_post(http_request request)
{
    TRACE(L"\nhandle POST\n");

    utility::string_t input;
    input = request.to_string();
    utility::ofstream_t out("output.txt");
    out << input;
    out.close();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    http_listener listener(L"http://localhost:8080");
    listener.support(methods::POST, handle_post);


    try
    {
        listener
             .open()
             .then([&listener]() {TRACE(L"\nstarting to listen\n"); })
             .wait();

         while (true);
    }
    catch (exception const & e)
    {
        wcout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

One of the errors i'm getting:

unresolved external symbol" __declspec(dllimport) public:_thiscall web::uri::uri(wchar_t const*)" (__imp_??0uri@web@@QAE@PB_W@Z) referenced in function_main

Would appreciate if someone could point out to me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

have you included cpprest.lib as your additional dependencies in Linker->Input. Exact name depends if you are doing static or dynamic link of the cpprest library.

Also you might need to add _NO_ASYNCRTIMP preprocessor definition, if you are doing static linking.

Hope this helps